# Front-end back-end not showsing all info

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I was trying to send the data from the front-end to back-end using expressJS and axios

however when I try to check the playload it's has all the info but the response always has the 'name' only

```
import axios, { Axios } from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


export default function RegisterPage () {

    const [name,setName]=useState('');
    const [email,setEmail]=useState('');
    const [password,setPassword]=useState('');
    
    function registerUser(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        
axios.post('/register', {
 name,
 email,
 password
        
        })
```

the front-end file

```
app.post('/register', (req,res)=> { 
  const {name,email,password} = req.body;
  res.json(name,email,password);  

  
  });
```

Comment: can you check the response before destructuring the response

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote an express backend but I would try to encapsulate the values inside the same object:  res.json({name, email, password})

Comment: @Cptn-Tomatoe is right, this function takes only one argument